# Azure Cognitive Search filter fields having mixed datatype

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have created a field (named as *'value'*) in my Azure Cognitive Search Index which may have values of different data types (for example, string, string array, object array). While creating the Index, I have configured type for this *value* field as "Edm.String" and due to which data in my Index is stored as:

1. For string fields: "value": "value1"
2. For string arrays: "value": "["value1","value2"]"
3. For object arrays: "value": "[ {"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}]"
   Basically, my complex fields are getting stored in form of strings as I have defined these as "Edm.String". Hence, *filters* are not working properly in this.
   For example: If I try to filter data where **"key1":"value1"** (in point 3), the data is not getting matched as the actual value is **"[ {"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}]"**.

Can anyone please guide on how to proceed in this case?

Note: I cannot make the *value* field of type "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)" because of the values are in string format and Indexer fails in this case. Also, I cannot modify the way database is structured.

Answer (score 0):

We have a method called `search.in` where we can apply filter on the collection created using **`Edm.String`**. We have different other methods mentioned like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-odata-filter-orderby-syntax), which speaks about the **$filter** and other operations using **Edm.String**.

We have the choice of using the below syntax for filtering

```
keyphrases/any(t: search.in(t, 'database'))
```